# libgdx next screen remembers touch input from previous screen

Tags: touch, libgdx

In my game after clicking on play button from splash screen.
i am switching to game screen.

In game screen I have update method which is updating the positions of my actors depending upon screen touch..

so here I have checked 
`if ( Gdx.input.justTouched() ) {....}`

its giving me true even i am not touching to screen..
  may be it is remembering the last touch from splash screen...

Or may be the different reason that i am not getting ..

..

```
thanks.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation of justTouched() http://libgdx.l33tlabs.org/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/Input.html#justTouched() doesn't really tell us what "just" means. Might be the touch from the splash screen.

Use isTouched() instead which should not have that problem.

Furthermore I think it's smarter to implement InputProcessor http://libgdx.l33tlabs.org/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/InputProcessor.html so you can handle the events right when they occur, and you don't need to check every frame.